# How to show convergence in distribution of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, weak-convergence

We have a sequence of random variables $\displaystyle (X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ satisfies ${ E( X_n) \to 1 }$ and ${ E( X_n ^{2} ) \to 1}$. Show that $\displaystyle (X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converges in distribution, and to what distribution.

This looks like a fairly easy one, but I just don't know where to start. Much appreciated if someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(X_n-1)^{2}=EX_n^{2}-2EX_n+1\to 1-2+1=0$. So $X_n \to 1$ in mean square. This implies $X_n \to 1$ in probability, hence also in distribution.

Comment: I love the flavor of proof. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By using the Markov's inequality for any $a>0$ and $\mu=E\{X_n\}$ $$\Pr\{(X_n-\mu)^2\ge a\}\le {E\{(X_n-\mu)^2\}\over a}={\sigma_{X_n}^2\over a}$$since $\sigma_{X_n}^2\to 0$, for any $a>0$ we obtain $$\Pr\{(X_n-\mu)^2\ge a\}\to 0$$which shows that $X_n$ tends to a **degenerate distribution around $1$**.

Comment: Very clear explanation. Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy to help!